# Compute subtotal rows in a spreadsheet

Tags: excel, spreadsheet, google-sheets, openoffice-calc, libreoffice

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
   A         B               C
1  Section   Task            Dev Hours
2  4         PROJECT TOTAL   =c3+....
3  4.1       Public site     =c4+c5+...
4  4.1.1     User Accounts   2
5  4.1.2     Daily Deal      =sum(c6:c7)
6  4.1.2.1   Model           4
7  4.1.2.2   View            2
```

What I'd like is a better way to compute subtotals in column C for non-leaf rows. Using =sum is error-prone as I add/remove rows. Also I can only use it when all children are leaves, or it will double-count things. Using addition is even more error-prone and extra annoying. Is there some way to tell {Excel,OpenOffice,LibreOffice,Google Documents} to roll up the values in column C for all following child rows, based on the outline numbers in column A? I would love a function like this:

```
=sum_children(A2)
```

Where A2 is the cell with the current row's outline number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array formula to do this.  For the formula below, I've assumed that your `Section` values are sorted as you have shown above.  In `C2`, paste the following and enter the formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>:

```
=SUM(IF(LEFT($A3:$A$7,LEN(A2))=A2,IF(ISERROR(FIND(".",$A3:$A$7,LEN(A2)+2)),$C3:$C$7,0),0))
```

You should then be able to copy cell C2 and paste onto any of the cells below that represent a parent section.

Basically this formula checks Column A below the current row for strings that start with the current section and only sums the dev hours for those that don't have an additional period after the current section + "."

To avoid having to update these formulas when you add additional sections to your table, you can make the endpoints of the arrays (`A7` and `C7` in the example formula) a row way beyond the bottom of your table (e.g. `A50` and `C50`). This could affect performance slightly, but really only if you go overboard and give yourself a 50,000 row pad.

Comment: Wow, you are an Excel wizard. In Google Docs, this works if you wrap the whole thing in `=arrayfunction()` instead of typing `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter`.

Comment: I'm a little worried that `+2` is going to break if an outline level ever has two digits, like `4.1.10.2`.

Comment: Actually the `+2` should be fine in all cases. All it does is make sure the `FIND()` function starts looking for additional periods after the current section plus another period. So, for instance, if the current section is `4.1.10`, it look at the following sections starting at the 8th (i.e. after the 6 characters of `4.1.10` plus a following period). It will find any matching section that doesn't have another period after that character, including `4.1.10.10` and `4.1.10.100000`.

Comment: Ah, you're right: it's for hopping over the period, not the digit. Thanks!